# Specifying reduce functor for mappedReduce

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

I am using QtConcurrent to run a certain task in parallel. However, i have run into a problem when i trued to change to using mappedReduced instead of map.

Here is the code i used:

```
struct ProcMapWrapper {
  ConcurrentProcessTask *instance;
  ProcMapWrapper(ConcurrentProcessTask *w): instance(w) {}
  QString & operator()(const QString& data) {
    return instance->map(data);
  }
  ProcMapWrapper(const ProcMapWrapper & src)
  {
      instance = src.instance;
  }
  typedef QString result_type;
};

struct ProcReduceWrapper {
  ConcurrentProcessTask *instance;
  ProcReduceWrapper(ConcurrentProcessTask *w): instance(w) {}
  void operator()(int &number, const QString &fname) {
    return instance->reduce(number,fname);
  }
  ProcReduceWrapper(const ProcReduceWrapper & src)
  {
      instance = src.instance;
  }
  typedef int result_type;
};

ProcMapWrapper mw(this);
ProcReduceWrapper rw(this);
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(_files.begin(),_files.end(),mw,rw));
```

The idea is to use processOneItem function to generate stage1Data struct from input string, then in reduce function clear up and save the result in appropriate container.

I have made a bit of research that has led me to [this source file](http://www.passcal.nmt.edu/~azevedo/For_Derick/KITCHEN_3rd_Party_May_2012/CentOS6/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/src/corelib/concurrent/qtconcurrentmap.cpp), that refers to [these code snippets](http://www.qt.gitorious.org/+qt-developers/qt/staging/blobs/b37ac454832a23c17418f5ebca8928b63fe02289/doc/src/snippets/code/src_corelib_concurrent_qtconcurrentmap.cpp) . In there, template for map functor is given as follows:

```
struct Scaled 
{ 
     Scaled(int size) 
     : m_size(size) { } 

     typedef QImage result_type; 

     QImage operator()(const QImage &image) 
     { 
         return image.scaled(m_size, m_size); 
     } 

     int m_size; 
}; 

 QList<QImage> images = ...; 
 QFuture<QImage> thumbnails = QtConcurrent::mapped(images, Scaled(100));
```

This indeed works for `map` and `mapped` functions of QtConcurrent, however my attempts to make a reduce functor with the same pattern lead to these errors again:

> ..\qt_photoaud\task.cpp(230) : error C2893: Failed to specialize
>   function template
>   'QFuture::ResultType>
>   QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)'
>           With the following template arguments:
>           'QList::iterator'
>           with
>           [
>               T=QString
>           ]
>           'ProcMapWrapper'
>           'ProcReduceWrapper' ..\qt_photoaud\task.cpp(230) : error C2783: 'QFuture
>   QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)'
>   : could not deduce template argument for 'ResultType'
>           c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtcore../../src/corelib/concurrent/qtconcurrentmap.h(152) : see declaration of 'QtConcurrent::mappedReduced'
>   ..\qt_photoaud\task.cpp(230) : error C2893: Failed to specialize
>   function template
>   'QFuture::ResultType>
>   QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(const Sequence
>   &,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)'
>           With the following template arguments:
>           'QList::iterator'
>           with
>           [
>               T=QString
>           ]
>           'QList::iterator'
>           with
>           [
>               T=QString
>           ]
>           'ProcMapWrapper' ..\qt_photoaud\task.cpp(230) : error C2783: 'QFuture QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(const Sequence
>   &,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for 'ResultType'
>           c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtcore../../src/corelib/concurrent/qtconcurrentmap.h(125) : see declaration of 'QtConcurrent::mappedReduced'

Is reduce functor really defined and/or recognized at all? How does QtPrivate::ReduceResultType::ResultType works? What does it need?

Edit: Assuming that functors are compabile with boost::function, i tried specifying first_argument_type, second_argument_type, arg1_type and arg2_type in reduce functor. but that did not help any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
struct concurrentProcessDBMapper
{
    typedef stage1Data result_type;
    stage1Data operator()(QString fname)
    {
        return concurrentProcessDBMap(fname);
    }
};

struct concurrentProcessDBReducer
{
    DatabaseConcurrentProcessTask *instance;
    concurrentProcessDBReducer(DatabaseConcurrentProcessTask *i)
    {
        instance = i;
    }

    void operator()(int & number, const stage1Data in)
    {
        //concurrentProcessDBReduce
        instance->reduce(number,in);
    }
};
...
    QFutureWatcher<int> futureWatcher;

    QList<QString> _filesInWork;

...
futureWatcher.setFuture(
     QtConcurrent::mappedReduced
         <int, QList<QString>, concurrentProcessDBMapper,concurrentProcessDBReducer>
                            (_filesInWork,concurrentProcessDBMapper(),concurrentProcessDBReducer(this)));
...
```

To summarise, with type transformation going like -(map)->-(reduce)->, map functor has result_type defined as stage1Data, and reduce functor does not have any result_type defined at all. Future watcher has its typed defined as reduce result (that is, type of its first out argument) - in my case, int - and template parameters for mappedReduced are explicitely defined.